# How can I change the jolting "Game Ready" sound?

Tags: dota-2

I don't like the jolt I get from the obnoxiously loud game ready sound for match making. Is there a way to change it to something more relaxing like `C:\Windows\Media\Alarm02.wav`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed it using the following method :

- Go in the folder `Steam\steamapps\common\dota 2 beta\dota\sound\ui\stingers`
- Place your new match making sound/music in it
- Name the file *match_ready_no_focus*
- Start the game and enjoy

Comment: works fine with '.wav' files too!

Comment: I happened to be talking about the out if game sound, but have you found the in game sound too?

Comment: @Louis I'll check tonight when I'm at home, I can't for now

Comment: @Louis From the top of my head try "match_ready_focus" but I'm not 100% sure